# Silverlight How to load a usercontrol in a page based upon a listbox selection

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, datatemplate

I am trying to work though the best approach to accomplish the following. Within a page I have it divided into two section. On the left a listbox and the right is empty. (Grid etc). What I would like to accomplish is when an item is selected from the listbox a different user control loads in the right panel.  For example if I have three items (one, two three) selecting one would load a red user control, two would load a blue user control and three a green user control.

I was taking this approach since Content Template / Data template selectors are not available in SL. However if anyone has another suggestion I would be grateful for your thoughts.

I'm creating this with MVVM in mind and traditionally I have managed this within the code behind of the user control however I have seen mention of how this could be managed within the ViewModel as well.

Any suggestions or guidance on a best approach is always appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind both listbox selected item and user control visibility properties to the same property in the viewModel.
Then just use a valueConverter for each user control to switch on/off the visibility.

Please tell me if i should elaborate/add a code sample.

Comment: Thanks Michael. So you would use a value converter to set the visibility on each user control? Would it make more sense to just dump the xaml into Grid elements if they are simple in layout vs a UC and then manage the visibility of these elements? If have the time I would appreciate an example of how the property piece works in conjunction with the value converter. Thanks again

Comment: @randyc, you can just write XAML as grid elements and still use the value converters. Use of user controls is recommended usually due to the ability of reusing them later in other places, and also separating complicated xaml from the page. I personnaly prefer working with UC.
I have uploaded a sample project to the following address:
[link](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=c98bb2b1515f256f&sc=documents&uc=1&id=C98BB2B1515F256F%212203#)

hope it will help you. 
Please update on how it went.

Comment: @ Michael, Thanks for the feedback Michael and thanks also for the sample I really appreciate your time